How to combine Authentication using Azure AD with username and Password stored in database?
Our requirement is as follows:

Sign-in with Microsoft account using Azure AD
Sign-in with username and password stored in database

If I sign-in with username and password stored in database, then I have to authenticate the user and get the ID and access tokens from Azure AD.
How to achieve this?
Please help!!
We tried Azure AD and we are able to sign-in and get the tokens with all the permissions assigned to the user but we don't know how to sign-in the username and password and get the tokens with all the permissions and role.

You can make use of Authorization code flow or ROPC flow to generate the access token by signing in with the username and password.

ROPC flow isn't recommended by Microsoft due to security risk.
Hence you can make use of Authorization code flow to generate access token for the user with all permissions and roles assigned to the user.

You need to register an application in Microsoft Entra and use token endpoints to generate access token if you are choosing Azure AD Authentication.
And grant permissions to the application (if you are using custom API, you can grant permission to custom API):
For sample, I granted Microsoft Graph API permission:

Generated auth code using below endpoint:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345

Sign in with the username and password:


Now generate the access token by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:RedirectURL
client_secret:ClientSecret


The above access token will contain the roles and permissions assigned to the user and you can perform actions that is access Azure resources and APIs based on your requirement.

You can decode the access token in jwt.ms and check the scopes claim.

References:
Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft
microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/lib/msal-react at dev · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js · GitHub by hectormmg
